# Vanishing of a certain Tor

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I am reading about the construction of the Affine Grassmannian in Dennis Gaitsgory's seminar [notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Oct13(AffGr).pdf)
and there are some commutative algebra facts that I am not able to figure out by myself apparently, like the following:

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $A$ a finite type $k$-algebra and $A\subseteq B$ some (non finite type) extension. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A[[t]]$-module which is flat over $A$ (actually finite free over $A$) and $t$ acts nilpotently on $M$. Then, $\operatorname{Tor}^{A[[t]]}_n(M,B[[t]])=0$ for all $n>0$.

Intuitively, since we get $B[[t]]$ from $A[[t]]$ by extending only the coefficient ring $A$ in a "free" way, flatness over $A$ of $M$ should suffice, but I can't make it into a proof. Notice that $A[[t]]\otimes _A B\ne B[[t]]$ in general. Am I missing something obvious?

#### Edit:

After reading it again, it seems that the only additional hypothesis I missed is that $t$ acts nilpotently on $M$ which I think does not follow from what I have written. The relevant place in the notes is the first line on page 7 and a bit before that.

Comment: What means "$t$ acts nilpotently on $M$"?

Comment: This means that $t^n$ acts as zero on $M$ for some $n\ge 1$ or equivalently, that the action of $A[[t]]$ factors through $A[t]/t^n$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt (could be mistakes so be wary!).

We have
$$
M \otimes_{A[[t]]}^{\mathbb{L}} B[[t]] \cong (M \otimes_{A[[t]]}^{\mathbb{L}} A[[t]]/t^n) \otimes_{A[[t]]}^{\mathbb{L}} B[[t]]. 
$$

By associativity this is (quasi-isomorphic) to 
$$
M \otimes_{A[[t]]}^{\mathbb{L}} B[[t]]/t^n.
$$
Since $A[[t]] \rightarrow A[[t]]/t^n$ is surjective, this is the same as
$$
M \otimes_{A[[t]]/t^n}^{\mathbb{L}} B[[t]]/t^n.$$

And this satisfies the conclusion you want because of your conditions on $M$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately I don't quite follow. Could you please explain what does the $L$ above the $\otimes$ means? and perhaps elaborate on how does this prove the claimed result?

Comment: The 'L' means "left derived". Given a ring $R$ and modules $M$ and $N$, $M \otimes_R^{\mathbb{L}} N$ is a chain complex whose homology is Tor^R_*(M, N). See, e.g., Weibel's book. Your result is equivalent to the claim that the firs complex I wrote down in my answer is quasi-isomorphic to a complex concentrated in degree zero. My argument tells you it is enough to show this for the last complex I wrote down

Comment: In other words, given your conditions, I have shown it is enough to know that $Tor_n^{A[t]/t^n}(M, B[t]/t^n) = 0$ for $n>0$, and this is elementary since $M$ is flat over $A$ and $A \rightarrow A[t]/t^n$ is faithfully flat.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will have to think about it for a while!

Answer (score 0):

**New attempt:**

Lemma 24.6.6 in Vakil's AG notes states:

> Suppose $N$ is an $R$-module and $t\in R$ is not a zero divisor on $N$. Then for any $R/(t)$-module $M$, we have 
>   $$
> \operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M,N)=\operatorname{Tor}_i^{R/(t)}(M,N/(t)).
> $$
>   (Actually it is stated with the roles of $M$ and $N$ reversed, but Tor is symmetric.)

Now, in our case, $R=A[[t]]$, $t^n$ is not a zero divisor on $N=B[[t]]$ and $M$ is actually an $A[[t]]/(t^n)$-module so we get

$$
\operatorname{Tor}_i^{A[[t]]}(M,B[[t]])=\operatorname{Tor}_i^{A[[t]]/(t^n)}(M,B[[t]]/(t^n)).
$$

Take a free resolution $F_{\bullet}\to B$ over $A$. Tensoring with $A[[t]]/(t^n)$ over $A$, we get
$$
F_{\bullet}\otimes _A A[[t]]/(t^n)\to B[[t]]/(t^n)
$$

Which is a free resolution of $B[[t]]/(t^n)$ over $A[[t]]/(t^n)$. Now, tensor with $M$ over $A[[t]]/(t^n)$, we get the complex

$$
(F_{\bullet}\otimes _A A[[t]]/(t^n)) \otimes _{A[[t]]/(t^n)} M \cong F_{\bullet}\otimes _A M
$$

On the on hand, its homology are precisely the Tor-s we want to calculate and on the other, it is exact by $A$-flatness of $M$, so its homology is zero.

---

**Edit (final, I hope...)**: The second step is exactly the flat base change of Tor, but on the *other* module. The map $A\to A[[t]]/(t^n)$ is flat so we get
$$
\operatorname{Tor}_i^{A}(M,B)=\operatorname{Tor}_i^{A[[t]]/(t^n)}(M,B[[t]]/(t^n))
$$

Where we used $B\otimes _A A[[t]]/(t^n)=B[[t]]/(t^n)$ (for this, the reduction mod $t^n$ was necessary!) and now the LHS is zero by $A$-flatness of $M$.